# A function stops all my other ones

Tags: javascript, function

Before the register popup function everything works fine, but then every function stops.
It is a facebook like chat function
I have checked if there isn't a spelling mistake, didn't found it
**Here is my function:**

```
//creates markup for a new popup. Adds the id to popups array.
function register_popup(id, name) {
  for (var iii = 0; iii < popups.length; iii++) {
    //already registered. Bring it to front.
    if (id == popups[iii]) {
      Array.remove(popups, iii);
      popups.unshift(id);
      calculate_popups();
      return;
    }
  }

  var element = '<div class="popup-box chat-popup" id="' + id + '">';
  element = element + '<div class="popup-head">';
  element = element + '<div class="popup-head-left">' + name + '</div>';
  element = element + '<div class="popup-head-right"><a href="javascript:close_popup(\'' + id + '\');">&#10005;</a></div>';
  element = element + '<div style="clear: both"></div></div><div class="popup-messages"></div><input type="text" style="height:24px;"></div>';

  document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].innerHTML = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].innerHTML + element;
  popups.unshift(id);
  calculate_popups();
}

//calculate the total number of popups suitable and then populate the toatal_popups variable.
function calculate_popups() {
  var width = window.innerWidth;
  if (width < 540) {
    total_popups = 0;
  } else {
    width = width - 200;
    //320 is width of a single popup box
    total_popups = parseInt(width / 320);
  }
  display_popups();
}

//recalculate when window is loaded and also when window is resized.
window.addEventListener("resize", calculate_popups);
window.addEventListener("load", calculate_popups);
//displays the popups. Displays based on the maximum number of popups that can be displayed on the current viewport width
function display_popups() {
  var right = 220;
  var iii = 0;
  for (iii; iii < total_popups; iii++) {
    if (popups[iii] != undefined) {
      var element = document.getElementById(popups[iii]);
      element.style.right = right + "px";
      right = right + 320;
      element.style.display = "block";
    }
  }
  for (var jjj = iii; jjj < popups.length; jjj++) {
    var element = document.getElementById(popups[jjj]);
    element.style.display = "none";
  }
}

Array.remove = function(array, from, to) {
  var rest = array.slice((to || from) + 1 || array.length);
  array.length = from < 0 ? array.length + from : from;
  return array.push.apply(array, rest);
};

//this variable represents the total number of popups can be displayed according to the viewport width
var total_popups = 0;

//arrays of popups ids
var popups = [];

//this is used to close a popup
function close_popup(id) {
  for (var iii = 0; iii < popups.length; iii++) {
    if (id == popups[iii]) {
      Array.remove(popups, iii);

      document.getElementById(id).style.display = "none";

      calculate_popups();

      return;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you get any messages in your _Console_?

Comment: What is `Array.remove`?

Comment: When you ask a question it helps to either provide more information or a working example. "but then every function stops" doesn't tell anyone anything. And what Bamar said, what is Array.remove? Did you add this yourself?

Comment: If you don't know **exactly** where the problem is occurring try using breakpoints. Welcome to Stackoverflow.

Comment: I don't know javascript, i simply downloaded this code.Array.remove is for removing the popup